# dprint keep double quotes inside React Elements on a single quote default settings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formatting

I am trying to set up dprint on an already existing project.
My current settings are simple:

```json
"typescript": {
    "quoteStyle": "preferSingle",
    "lineWidth": 120,
    "semiColons": "asi"
}
```

This allows me to change all double quotes to single quotes unless necessary.
I would like to however make an exception for this, and default to double quotes instead when inside a React Element.

```js
const randomString = 'hello i am a random string'  // this should default to single quotes

(<Text fontSize="lg">some text</Text>) // this "lg" should default to double quotes
```

Is this possible?
I had prettier set up previously, and it allowed double quotes on React, but I think it was just ignoring the Element part of the code.